# Dynamic height of table is not set

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to set dynamic height of table. But it is not working when I log height of table it is showing me dynamic height but not set to actual table.

Here is my code:

```
CGRect table_frame;
table_frame=table_sender.frame;
NSLog(@"table fram: %f",table_frame.size.height); //got table height 444
float height = [senderHistoryDataArray count]  * 40 +40 ; // 4*25.00
NSLog(@"height of table: %f",height);  //got this height 200
if(height>=444){
    table_frame.size.height=444;
}
else{
    table_frame.size.height=height;
    NSLog(@"height set");  //also displying this line in log
}

table_sender.frame=table_frame;
[table_sender reloadData];
```

Out Put:
[image]

when I uncheck autolayout it will work but it is just showing more part than previous.
[image]

Comment: I don't know the frame of your tableview in your picture.

Comment: actually i have set height 444 but when I compute height it is 200. But I dont know what that white color background is

Comment: do you want to change only the height table or are you talking about custom cells (each with other height?)

Comment: no just talking about height of table

Comment: Where are you calling the code you showed us?

Comment: maybe you can try to put your resize code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: if you are using AutoLayout then you can't set frames - if you do that you get wiered behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using AutoLayout then you can't set frames - if you do that you get wiered behaviour

Autolayout is sort of relative approach of placing UI components on screen.
For e.g Stand 100px behind me and 20px from left boundary (here i have used pixel - you can think of as meters think of it as playground)

Answer (score 0):

To set the height for row you need to set

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return rowHt[indexPath.row];
}
```

The each row can have different height only if you set it at

> heightForRowAtIndexPath

for that you need to select the corresponding rows from

> indexPath.row

If you are setting your tabelView from code it would look something like this

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)    UITableView     *table_sender;

self.table_sender = [[UITableView alloc]  initWithFrame:frameTable style:UITableViewStylePlain] ;
    self.table_sender.dataSource = self;
    self.table_sender.delegate = self;
```

where rowHt is a array of collection of height for each rows

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be some other code change your tableView's frame.

Use KVO to detect change of the frame of `UITableView`.

1、add an observer to it in you `viewDidLoad` method

```
[table_sender addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil] ;
```

2、implement `observeValueForKeyPath` method and add an breakpoint in it. When the breakpoint stop, check the call stack to find who change the frame.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", change) ; // add an breakpoint here
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context] ;
    }
}
```